# How to get skype call status

Tags: c#, skype

I am working on using skype API.I have to get the call Status returned by skype API.

Means when the called user changes the call status(picks call,misses call,discard.onhold,transfer etc.).

Or Calling User(caller side) cancel or finish call.I want to get the the call status in My application

```
 switch (CurrentStatus)
        {
            case TCallStatus.clsBusy:
                //Do something
                break;
            case TCallStatus.clsCancelled:
                //Do something
                break;
            case TCallStatus.clsFailed:
                //Do something
                 break;
            case TCallStatus.clsFinished:
               //Do something
                break;
    ..........
    .......
   }
```

Any help will be appeciable

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SKYPE4COMLib.Call.Status property`

```
if(yourInstance.Call.Status.Equals(TCallStatus.clsRinging)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Print status : {0}", Call.Status.ToString());
}
```